# hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, build, pipeline

I have triggered a build for my app in jenkins and it got failed by returning the following error

```
hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
```

Then I have reverted my changes and triggered it again even then the same error appeared with status fail.

Then I have triggered a build for other branch of the same project but it got success. I am new to Jenkins. Can anyone please help me understand the situation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Ansible playbooks can be very resource intensive. Especially when running against many hosts and/or using process forks, caching, etc.

It's common to see Ansible process allocating a lot of system memory. This can lead to an out-of-memory situation. Then the operating system picks and kills a running process in order to free the memory. This might affect your running Jenkins or Ansible.

Check your system logs for these out-of-memory exceptions.

For Linux use `dmesg -T | grep "Out of memory"` to filter out the relevant exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue with wrong filepath so suggestion is ***Check path of your war file***, before you have triggering a build for any app in jenkins.